# NGRX: Update input properties on child components without using ngOnChanges or async pipe

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am aware that by using Ngrx and the Containers/Presentational components architecture the container-smart component should be the one which communicates with the store and basically passes data to the child components through their exposed Input properties.
Also as a side note in the container component we are utilizing the OnPush change detection strategy.

The best option to achieve that, i suppose is to pass an observable to the template and unwrap it using async pipe.
Something like

```
//in the container's component.ts file 
this.file$ = this.store.pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$), select(getFiles))

// in the container's html.ts
<child-component [sth] = 'files$ | async'
```

In most cases though this value is used again inside the container's ts file for various reasons and that's why i am forced to use something like

```
 //in the container's component.ts file 
 this.store
  .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$), select(getFiles))
  .subscribe((files: Files[]) => { 
       this.files = files;
  }

// in the container's html.ts
<child-component [sth] = 'files'
```

So that makes me to either

Inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` in the Container and call the `detectChanges` function as soon as i get a value from the observable stream.

Or

Implement the `ngOnChanges` life-cycle hook  in the child component to check when the input value changes.

I am wondering, Is there a better way to achieve this update by not having to use manually detectChanges all over the place or have to write this boilerplate code in the child components with ngOnChanges ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need the `files` value in your component?
Not knowing your use-case I think it's a bad practice (but it might be necessary in your case).

I prefer to let Angular handle subscriptions on its own with the `async` pipe, to assign the local value you can use the `tap` operator.

```
this.file$ =  this.store
  .pipe(
    select(getFiles), // notice, we're not using takeUntil because Angular handles the subscription
    tap(files => { 
     this.files = files; // assign the value here
    })
)
```

Now you can use Observable as before:

```
<child-component [sth] = 'files$ | async'
```

Comment: Great Tim, i like this much better. Well the files value its just an example , a lot of times i am in need of using a specific value in more than one child component and also maybe in some kind of condition inside the containers methods.cheers

Comment: Moreover sometimes inside the Container component i need these values in order to pass them as payloads when dispatching other actions from the container . Should i always use selectors in effects to get state and remove it from the containers ?

Comment: We usually do async pipe it to the child, the child emits the value back to the parent to be able to dispatch it. Accessing state in your effects is fine imho, but only as a last resort.